# Solicitud ajax al cargar pagina termina con error a veces

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, ajax

Actualmente he estado probando y practicando laravel, ajax y datatables, arme una estructura básica de ajax para recibir y obtener unos datos al recargar la pagina es decir hago una solicitud a un controlador  y la respuesta al cargar la web me  trae unos datos  sencillos , cual serie el error? A veces al cargar por ejemplo una tabla ponte que 1 de 30 me genera un error y se va por el .fail() cosa que no entiendo,el código ajax es el siguiente

```
  function change_number(){
  $.ajax({
    url: comprasurl,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'action': 'change_number','fecha':$('#fecha_number').val()},
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    $('.content-numbers').html('');
    if (data > 0) {
      var content =data+1;
      $('.content-numbers').append('<input type="hidden" name="codigo_num" value="'+content+'">');
    }else{
      $('.content-numbers').append('<input type="hidden" name="codigo_num" value="1">');
    }
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
  });
}
```

En el archivo que recibe en este caso el controlador  simplemente tengo esto para pruebas y saco un alert o mensaje solo para probar y aprender pero a veces cuando le doy f5 en la consola pinta error y en la herramienta para ver el status sale como si no llegara a la dirección de la url  soy novato en este punto y quisiera implementar buenas practicas y todo pero que podría estar mal con mi código?
Esto ultimo seria la función store de mi controlador que recibe la data

```
public function store(Request $request){
    if ($request->has('action')) {
        $data = $request->all();
        switch ($data['action']) {
            case 'change_number':
                $fech = explode('-', $request->input('fecha'));
                $num = $this->compras::whereMonth('create_at',$fech[1])->whereYear('create_at',$fech[0])->orderBy('codigo_num','DESC')->first();
                if (!empty($num)) {
                    return $num->codigo_num;
                }else{
                    return 0;
                }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cual es el error cuando entra en fail()?